# Unable to see created date in the mapping while importing data for lead object using data loader

Tags: map, data, createddate, loader

I am using a Sandbox account to load data into the Leads object from a CSV via the data loader. However, I am unable to see the created date, last modified date (Audit fields) in the mapping window. Is something wrong with my approach.

Background:
I have created permission sets such as

1. API Enabled
2. Set Audit fields upon record creation
3. Modify all data
4. Update Records with Inactive Owners

Please let me know if I have missed something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels silly to ask, but did you actually assign the permission set to the user? I've made the mistake where I created it but never assigned it.

Finally, the data loader gets all the settings when you do the login at the start, not when you're making the insert. So if you logged in -> added permission -> went to insert then the fields wouldn't be there.

It's add permission -> login to data loader -> insert new records.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I actually had multiple set of permissions, one of which I  had missed assigning it to the user. I did that and it started working. Thanks again.